Spock happens exception：Too few invocations for: xxxx Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity)
I use Spock to test my java code，in detail to test method is MnsTemplate's sendMessage Method and unit test is in MnsTemplateTest, they are in below code.
In this unit test, I mock MNSClient、CloudQueue (the mnsClient.getQueueRef(queueName) return) and I expect that queue.putMessage method will execute once, but result is it's not execute.
Here is the java source code:
public class MnsTemplate {

    private MNSClient mnsClient;

    public MnsTemplate(MNSClient mnsClient) {
        this.mnsClient = mnsClient;
    }

    public void sendMessage(String queueName, String messageBody) {
        mnsClient.getQueueRef(queueName).putMessage(new Message(messageBody));
    }
}

and other associated source code：
public interface MNSClient {
    ...
    public CloudQueue getQueueRef(String queueName);
    ...
}

public final class CloudQueue {
   ...
   public Message putMessage(Message message) throws ServiceException,
        ClientException {
        SendMessageAction action = new SendMessageAction(serviceClient,
            credentials, endpoint);
        SendMessageRequest request = new SendMessageRequest();
        request.setMessage(message);
        request.setRequestPath(queueURL);
        return action.executeWithCustomHeaders(request, customHeaders);
    }
    ...
}

Here is the Spock unit test code:
import spock.lang.Specification
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*


class MnsTemplateTest extends Specification {

    MNSClient mnsClient
    CloudQueue queue

    def setup() {
        mnsClient = Mock(MNSClient)
        queue = mock(CloudQueue.class)
    }

    def "sendMessage should send a message to the queue"() {
        given:
        def mnsTemplate = new MnsTemplate(mnsClient)
        1 * mnsClient.getQueueRef("testQueue") >> queue

        when:
        mnsTemplate.sendMessage("testQueue", "Test Message")

        then:
        1 * queue.putMessage(new Message("Test Message"))
    }

due to CloudQueue.java is final type，so i use mockito-inline to mock.
when execute the unit test, it occurs error:
Too few invocations for:

1 * queue.putMessage(new Message("Test Message"))   (0 invocations)

Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):

None



    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.InteractionScope.verifyInteractions(InteractionScope.java:110)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.MockController.leaveScope(MockController.java:95)
    at MnsTemplateTest.sendMessage should send a message to the queue(MnsTemplateTest.groovy:26)

how to fix it and make it correct.
jdk is 21，spock-core's and spock-spring version is 2.4-M4-groovy-4.0

Are you using both mockito mocks and spock mocks? If so, why?

yes，due to CloudQueue is final，spock can't mock, so I do. And I do test，I change the code, use no final class replace CloudQueue, all use spock mock, it also not work.

sorry, it seems when all use Spock mock，it can work correctly. when partly use mockito it can't.

You cannot use a Mockito Mock and expect Spock being able to handle that properly.
Use Spock mocks.
If you cannot refactor your production code to make it properly testable but need to mock the final class, that's "fine", Spock can do that. (It internally uses the Mockito inline mock maker, but in Spock-y and Spock-compatible way).
https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.4-M4/all_in_one.html#mock-makers-mockito
